# How can I transform a list of graphs into a dataset to be used with PyTorch geometric?

Tags: python, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I have a database of 10 graphs in .graphml and I read them with NetworkX. After reading them I transform each NetworkX object into a Py Geometric object. After that, I created a list of Py Geometric objects and I created a batch from it using `torch_geometric.data.Batch.from_data_list()`, finally I attached the classification labels `pyg_list["y"]=y` to the batch. Unfortunately, when I divided the batch into training and testing datasets the `y` attribute disappeared. Does anyone know what happened?
The dataset `pyg_list`:

```
DataBatch(edge_index=[2, 1847712], mag=[42080], partition=[42080], role=[42080], weight=[1847712], num_nodes=42080, batch=[42080], ptr=[10], y=[9])
```

The test set `pyg_list[4:]`:

```
[Data(edge_index=[2, 96740], mag=[4704], partition=[4704], role=[4704], weight=[96740], num_nodes=4704),
 Data(edge_index=[2, 241552], mag=[4544], partition=[4544], role=[4544], weight=[241552], num_nodes=4544),
 Data(edge_index=[2, 296280], mag=[4192], partition=[4192], role=[4192], weight=[296280], num_nodes=4192),
 Data(edge_index=[2, 317488], mag=[4128], partition=[4128], role=[4128], weight=[317488], num_nodes=4128)]
```

Thank you in advance.